# Delta Hedging: Clarification example of the book "Hull, Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives"

Tags: options, finance, derivatives, delta-hedging

> By "Hull, Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives":
>
> [image]
>
> Suppose that, in figure,the stock price is \$100 and the option price
>   is \$10. Imagine an investor who has sold 20 call option
>   contracts—that is, options on 2,000 shares. The investor’s position
>   could be hedged by buying $0.6 \times  2,000 =1,200 $ shares.  The
>   gain (loss) on the stock position would then tend to offset the loss
>   (gain) on the option position.
>
> For example, if the stock price goes up by \$1 (producing a gain of
>   \$1,200 on the shares purchased), the option price will tend to go up
>   by $0.6 \times  \$1 = \$0.60$ (producing a loss of \$1,200 on the
>   options written);

**Why the option price that will tend to go up by \$ 0.60, produce a loss of \$1,200?**

If strike price $K= \$ 50$, we have that investor loss:

$$(\$ 100 - \$ 50 ) \times 2,000 = \$ 100.000$$

If the stock price goes up by $1, the investor loss:

$$(\$ 101 - \$ 50 ) \times 2,000 = \$ 102.000$$

so, if the stock price goes up by \$1, the option contract produce a loss of \$ 2.000

Why?

Comment: One call option is worth a 100 equity shares in the example

Comment: The investor has SOLD options on 2000 shares. He loses if the price goes up. He loses 2000*0.6 = 1200  if the price of options goes up by 0.6

Comment: If strike price $K= \$ 50$, we have that investor loss:

$$(\$ 100 - \$ 50 ) \times 2,000 = \$ 100.000$$

If the stock price goes up by \$1, the investor loss:

$$(\$ 101 - \$ 50 ) \times 2,000 = \$ 102.000$$

so, if the stock price goes up by \$1, the option contract produce a loss of \$ 2.000

It is not correct. Why?

Comment: You are using the formula $2000(S-K)^+ $ which is the value at expiration, the book is talking about the change in option value on a day before expiration. The option cannot be exercised yet, so it's market value is not given by your formula.

Comment: Sorry if I insist and tank you for your comment but I'm a bit confused. If the call option price is \$ 10 and the investor sells 20 option contracts, the investor earns from the sale of options: $20 \times \$ 10  = \$ 200  $
If the price of the option goes up by \$ 0.6, the investor could earn $20 \times \$ 10.6  = \$ 212  $. So the difference is $ \$ 12$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We denote by $C(S_0, K)$ the price for a call option with payoff $(S_T-K)^+$ at the option maturity $T.$ Here $S_0=100$ is the spot stock price. 
Generally, 
\begin{align*}
C(S_0, K) \ne (S_0-K)^+.
\end{align*} 
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
C(S_0+\Delta, K)-C(S_0, K) \approx \frac{\partial C}{\partial S_0} \Delta,
\end{align*}
where $\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_0}=0.6$ is the delta hedge ratio. If the stock price go up by $\Delta = \$1$, the shorted option position will loss
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_0} \Delta = 0.6 \times \$1 = \$0.60.
\end{align*}
Then the whole option position loss is $2,000 \times \$0.60 = \$1,200$.

Comment: My confusion stems from the fact that the value of 1 option contract is \$ 10 written on 100 shares ($2.000 / 20$ option contracts).
$$ C (S_0, K) = \$ 10 $$
So
$$20 option contracts  \times \$ 10 = \$ 200 $$

Could you clarify this aspect?

Comment: After the option is sold, that sold option price does not matter any more. Here, we consider the option price change  as the underlying stock changes.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I don't understand why the option position loss is $2,000 \times 0,60 = \$ 1,200$ ?

Comment: The option notional is 2,000: each option has notional of 100, and you sold 20 options; that is, options on 2,000 shares, as you described.

Comment: OK! I got it. Thank you so much for clarification and for patience